# How can I determine if a prexisting slab on grade is frost protected?

Tags: garage, foundation, slab, frost

I have a detached garage that was built sometime in the 50's.  At some point it seems that an addition was made to it to create a shop.  There was an old oil burning stove in there as well on the garage side.

I would like to convert the garage to an ADU but the county says I probably can't do it if the slab on grade (they don't think it is) isn't a frost protected one.  I'd like to know if there is any way that I can simply check to see if it was in fact built with frost protection (but I doubt it).  I have attached a picture of the building to give you an idea of what it looks like (yes it has asbestos siding I know).

I'm in climate zone 5b.  Thank you for your help and consideration.

Picture:

[image]

Comment: Your picture didn't get added. Please [edit] to include it.

Comment: Sorry about that, picture now included.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Built sometime in the 1950's" == almost certainly NOT frost protected.

Dig at an edge and observe the lack of insulation. If a flock of pigs happens to have been flying North by Northwest overhead when it was built in the dark of the moon, observe the insulation. That's for a "frost protected shallow foundation" nobody was building 70 years ago.

Depending how your county defines "frost protected" the other thing you could more plausibly find in a 1950's slab would be a frostwall to a footing below frostline. You could even excavate all around and insulate that to make it more to modern standards.